# symfony2 redirect in constructor

Tags: php, symfony

I want to do a redirect in the constructor in a specific sutiation.
I tried to do it like this:

```
return new \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse($url);
```

and like this:

```
return $this->redirect($url);
```

But it doesn't work. In every other method it works, but for some reason when this code is in the constructor it doesn't work. There are no errors or warnings.

If you need more info ask in the comments.
Thanks for the time.

Comment: In the constructor of what?

Comment: Bad idea to use redirect in constructors

Comment: @Markus Kottländer:
In the constructor of a controller of mine.
Victor: Why is it a bad idea?

Comment: Constructor return only object of the class(object of controller in your case), and it can't return redirect object

Comment: Are you sure you know what a ctor is? Can you show us some code?

Comment: Yeah i know what a constructor is. It`s called when you make an instance of a class and my url points to a method of this class(method is not static), in which constructor i need to make a redirect. The constructor code is executed but the redirct doesn`t work. This should work, so maybe this is specific to symfony2.

Answer (score 3):

Bad idea to redirect from controller directly. I would rather throw some custom exception.

```
class FooController{
    public function __construct(){
        if ( some_test ){
            throw RedirectionException(); // name it however you like
        }
    }
}
```

Then, in `Symfony`, setup the `ExceptionListener` which will evaluate class-type of `Exception` thrown and redirect you application to another URL, if necessary. This service will most likely depend on `@routing` service to generate alternate URL destination.

**<kbd>Service config:</kbd>**

```
services:
    kernel.listener.your_listener_name:
        class: Your\Namespace\AcmeExceptionListener
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.exception, method: onKernelException }
```

**<kbd>Listener class:</kbd>**

```
class AcmeExceptionListener
{
    public function onKernelException(GetResponseForExceptionEvent $event)
    {
        // You get the exception object from the received event
        $exception = $event->getException();

        if ( $exception instanceof RedirectionException ){
            $response = new RedirectResponse();

            $event->setResponse($response);
        }
    }
}
```

This way to can maintain single error handling and redirection logic. Too complicated?

Answer (score 1):

Bad idea to use redirect in constructors. Constructor return only current `object of the class` (object of controller in your case), and it can't return `redirect object`. Maybe you can solve your task in route, using `FrameworkBundle:Redirect:urlRedirect`:

```
# redirecting the root
root:
    path: /
    defaults:
        _controller: FrameworkBundle:Redirect:urlRedirect
        path: /app
        permanent: true
```

Check examples in [How to Configure a Redirect without a Custom Controller](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/routing/redirect_in_config.html#redirecting-using-a-path)

Comment: Ok, but how can i make a condition. For Example i have a url like "mysite.com/product" and when visiting this url if for example $this->session->get('some flag') is false to redirect it to a different url or if it`s true to continue as normal.

Comment: It's need to realize in controller `action` directly

Comment: yeah, but i need to implement this logic all araund the methods instead in only one place(this is why i want to make this redirect in the constructor).
I could do this with firewalls and security areas, but this isn`t worth it for only one case for me.

Comment: You can also to route all paths to one main `action`, in which you can use `redirect` or `forwarding` request to another `action` with depending on different conditions. Read about [forwarding](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/controller.html#forwarding) in controller