# How to send and show messages in AngularJS and Symfony2 project

Tags: angularjs, symfony

I'm trying to capture errors inside Symfony2 controller as this code shows:

```
public function indexAction($parent_id = 0) {
        $response['message'] = "";
        $breadcrumbs = array();

        $response['entities'] = array();

        if (!$entity) {
            throw $this->createNotFoundException('No se encontraron grupos de detalles');
        }

        ...

        return new JsonResponse($response);
    }

}
```

When `!$entity` is TRUE then as you see I generate a `NotFoundException` but I need to show a message to users in my AngularJS template. This is the code for the template:

```
<ul id="nav-info" class="clearfix">
    <li><a href="#/dashboard"><i class="icon-home"></i></a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Grupo de Meta-Detalles</a></li>
    <li class="active"><a href="#/detailsgroup/list">Listar</a></li>
</ul>
<h3 class="page-header page-header-top">Grupo de Meta-Detalles <small>Listado.</small></h3>

<table id="example-datatables" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="span1"></th>
            <th class="span1 hidden-phone">#</th>
            <th><i class="icon-bookmark"></i> Nombre</th>
            <th><i class="icon-bookmark"></i> Padre</th>
            <th><i class="icon-bolt"></i> Descripción</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="item in MetaDetailGroup">
            <td class="span1">
                <div class="btn-group">
                    <a href="#/products/edit/{% verbatim %}{{ item.id }}{% endverbatim %}" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Editar" class="btn btn-mini btn-success"><i class="icon-pencil"></i></a>
                    <a href="#/products/delete/{% verbatim %}{{ item.id }}{% endverbatim %}" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Eliminar" class="btn btn-mini btn-danger"><i class="icon-remove"></i></a>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td class="span1 hidden-phone">{% verbatim %}{{ item.id }}{% endverbatim %}</td>
            <td><a href="javascript:void(0)">{% verbatim %}{{ item.name }}{% endverbatim %}</a></td>
            <td><a href="javascript:void(0)">{% verbatim %}{{ item.parent }}{% endverbatim %}</a></td>
            <td>{% verbatim %}{{ item.description }}{% endverbatim %}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

How I can achieve this? I mean if there is nothing to show (!entity) then show a message to users, any help or advice?

Comment: Try to return `return new JsonResponse(array('message' => 'No se encontraron grupos de detalles'));` instead of throwing exception

Comment: @AleksejVasinov I could do that but then how I show in my template? I mean what is the right way?

Comment: It is much better idea to exception listener which will inspect the class type of exception and intercept response with `JSON`..

Comment: @jperovic I get lost, could you explain your solution?

Comment: if you are returning a json response, I would assume you are doing an ajax call?  If so, where is your javascript to handle it?  If you aren't doing an ajax call, then you need to render a template and return that in your controller.

Comment: @Reynier: See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21576425/symfony2-redirect-in-constructor/21580962#21580962 . I explained how to handle throws exceptions, in general. Should be useful to you as well ;) You will need to return `JsonReponse` instead of `Response`

Comment: @Sehael yes I'm doing a AJAX call since I'm using AngularJS and yes I'm returning a JSON

Comment: Also, while you would return `JSON`, I would advice against returning `HTTP 200` code. If you indeed need `NotFoundException` set HTTP code to 404 instead.

Comment: @jperovic I'll will return a message in the JSON I made for not handle this with redirection or 200/404 errors, in that case how I should show the message in AngularJS template?

Comment: yes, redirection is here just an example. As I wrote above, replace `RedirectResponse` with `JsonResponse`. In any case redirection is not possible in `AJAX` request...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have no AngularJS installed, so this is checked on JsFiddle :)

```
public function indexAction($parent_id = 0) {
    $response['message'] = "";
    $breadcrumbs = array();

    $response['entities'] = array();

    if (!$entity) {
        // Exception is replaced by message to your client-side script
        $response['message'] = 'No se encontraron grupos de detalles';
    }

    return new JsonResponse($response);
}
```

Make call to your symfony method (GET or POST):

```
$http.get("/api/index/?parent_id=666", {})
    .success(function(data, status, headers, config){
        // Would be nice to check status/message and to hide if no error
        $scope.ajaxResponse = data.message;
        // TODO: Handle your entities
    }).error(function(data, status, headers, config){
        $scope.ajaxResponse = status;
    });
```

In your view page (HTML) insert some Angular JS variable

```
    <tbody>
    <tr><td colspan="5">{{ajaxResponse}}</td></tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="item in MetaDetailGroup">
       ...
```