# Redirect from service in Symfony

Tags: php, redirect, service, symfony

I have a service that is requested in the constructor of my base controller, to make sure it always runs. This service checks some things from the database, and might error. If it errors, I want to redirect the user to a page that displays this error. I cannot find any way to accomplish this, as redirections can only be returned from a controller's action. What I want is to be able to 'return' a redirection from outside an action. What do I need to do to be able to redirect from my service? Do I have to implement my service differently, or not at all? I do not want to call this method manually on every action.

Relevant code:

```
// Every other controller in my bundle extends this one    
class Controller extends SymfonyController
{
    public function setContainer(ContainerInterface $container = null)
    {
        parent::setContainer($container);

        $this->containerInitialized();
    }

    protected function containerInitialized()
    {
        // Initialize my.service before running action of every page
        try {
            $this->get('my.service');
        } catch (SomeException $ex) {
            // I want redirection to happen here
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: I know I can use the controller kernel event to make something run on every page, which is what I am going to use. This still does not solve the redirection situation though.

Comment: I'd create a custom `RedirectException` that you can throw in your service, catch in the controller. The custom exception class should contain the url for the redirect.

Comment: @jszobody How would I actually perform this redirect from the controller? We are again not in an action at that point.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21576425/symfony2-redirect-in-constructor

Comment: @jszobody Thanks, I'll try that. If you add this as an answer in the meantime, I will accept it when I have checked if I can get it working.

Comment: @jszobody What a brilliant idea!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Services are not supposed to decide if a redirect should happen or not or how to deal with the client's request and response. A service is meant to just provide a service to the controller that can be used independent of how the controller was called.

If you have a service that can trigger a redirect to a specific site, how do you use that service in another controller, another site or even in a command-line interface where redirect do not exist? You cannot, and that is bad.

Error-Handling in services are meant to be done with custom exceptions. If a service comes to a point where it cannot continue normally, an exception is thrown that describes the error that happened, but not how the error should be handled. The decision of how to deal with the error/exception should be done by the controller or command depending on what makes sense in the context of the controller. If there are different types of errors that a service can cause, these different types should be distinguishable by the exception (or the data in the exception) on which the controller can make the decision to redirect somewhere (or not). A service or exception should never impose on the controller how it should handle the error, only provide information for the controller(s) or command(s) to decide by themself.

Comment: I agree with everything said, except for the fact that the controller should be in charge of every response. If you look at the security bundle, you see that a redirection is carried out based on a kernel event, like @jszobody pointed out. The only way I now know of to have a redirection happen based on a service (or any logic really) outside of an action is by handling its exceptions in a kernel event listener.